# schema name added to the table call in java with db2

Tags: java, db2

i probably got a strange problem.Call to a table in DB2 database table going with schema name.

```
   ERROR [main] WorkflowMailer (processcycle:463) - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, 
   SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=etwrms.WFT_EMAIL_TMP, DRIVER=3.57.82
```

Im passing url with schema name through a properties file.It worked fine with many SP call but thrown an error while calling a temporary table.The temporary table is present in the database.As per my observation call to the table is going with schemaname.tablename (etwrms.WFT_EMAIL_TMP , schema name appeneded here). Please let me know the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [error you are getting](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-204_sqlstate_42704.html) indicates that the table does not exist.

Note that temporary tables are not really "present in the database"; they only exist for the current session.  Even if you have two connections open at once to the same username, those are two different sessions; a table that was created and continues to exist in one connection will not be seen in the other connection.  Most likely this error indicates that you have created the temporary table in one session and are trying to use it in another session.

If you need more specific help, please show the statement that creates the table (there are different types of temporary tables with subtle differences), the statement that attempts to access the table, and describe when these occur in relation to each other.